# Using LGPL Library with Java static or Dynamic linking

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I've searched and read many posts about LGPL and C, and when I was able to find one that related to Java, my mind still didn't rest with ease, so I'll try to be more specific and hopefully get a viable guide lines, and I would eventually consult a lawyer obviously!

Setup:

- There is a LGPL library, lets call it **Lib-B**
- I have My Library which is based on **Lib-B** lets call it **My-Lib**

In my opinion **Lib-B** architecture is not well formulated, and I want to apply in **My-Lib** my own architecture and use **some** of the functions of **Lib-B**.

Problem is, that **Lib-B**, wraps the functions I want to access in a manner that does not suit the architecture of **My-Lib** so I've changed **Lib-B** and encapsulated (duplicated) the code lines I wanted/needed within a couple of objects still inside **Lib-B** and call these functions from **My-Lib**.

That is my current static setup...

=====================

The second thing I can do is to make my setup dynamic, so:

- I could create a Library that would define an interface with the functions **My-Lib** needs lets call it **Lib-A**.

Later, I will compile and link **My-Lib** with **Lib-A**, and let **Lib-B** implement the interface from **Lib-A**, and load **Lib-B** dynamically in **My-Lib**.

I understand that in both cases I must release my changes of **Lib-B** as LGPL as well and allow my end users access to the code etc... what about **My-Lib**?

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LGPL allows you to release My-lib without opening its source code.  That's the whole purpose of the LGPL; it provides a linking exception to allow users to link the LGPL library without opening their own source.

The LGPL still provides users with access to the source code of your changes to Lib-B, without preventing you from keeping the rest of your application closed-source.